# Using supremum property finding if the function is odd or even

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:\mathbb{R}->\mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property that for every $y \in\mathbb{R}$ the value of the expression $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}[xy-f(x)]$ is finite. Define
$g(y)=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R} }[xy-f(x)]$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then

a. g is even if f is even

b. f must satisfy $\lim_{|x|->\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$

c. g is odd if f is even

d. f must satisfy $\lim_{|x|->\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=-\infty$

I don't even know how to start. I tried to find suitable f and g and eliminate options. But this idea is also not working. This problem is really difficult for me. Kindly help me.

Comment: Whats the $i$ in $\sup_{x \in i}[xy-f(x)]$?

Comment: I am sorry. It's typo error. I made the necessary changes

Comment: Thanks. You can start with $f(x)=x^2$ and then compute the supremum. This would eliminate some options and maybe give you some starting point.